# 3rd Party Keyboard unavailable on uitext field - Swfitkey

Tags: ios, ios8

I just installed IOS 8 and Swiftkey , however going into my app I noticed that this keyboard does not appear as an option on my login screen.

I am guessing this needs to be actively enabled, but cannot see where or how.

Can someone point me to the documentation on this or explain how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Apple's "App Extension Programming Guide", it explicitly states that secure text entry fields cannot use 3rd party keyboards.  Doing so would be a huge security risk as a malicious keyboard app could capture your passwords.  Frankly, I'm more than a little concerned about 3rd party keyboards in general, as it makes it far too easy to create a key logger and send all your keystrokes out to a server on the Internet.